# StackOverflow Style Routes with Smart Redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, friendly-id

StackOverflow seems to have this style of routes for questions:

```
/questions/:id/*slug
```

Which is easy enough to achieve, both in routes and `to_param`.

However, StackOverflow seems to also redirect to that path when just an ID is passed.

**Example:**

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333
```

redirects to:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/
```

Same goes for any variation of the slug

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/some-random-stuff
```

Will still redirect to the same URL.

My question is: Is this type of redirection typically handled in the controller (comparing the request to the route) or is there a way to do this in `routes.rb`?

The reason I wouldn't think this possible in the `routes.rb` file is that typically, you don't have access to the object (so you couldn't get the slug based off the ID, right?)

For anyone interested, Rails 3.2.13 and also using [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Comment: maybe they use a regex to strip the id part of the param to do faster lookups and then redirect based on that. I also assume they keep the id in the url so that way if questions have the same title the url is unique.   
also this looks like controller logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I think I've got this.

I was looking into doing something with middleware, but then decided that's probably not the place for this type of functionality (since we need to access ActiveRecord).

So I ended up building a service object, known as a `PathCheck`. The service looks like this:

```
class PathCheck
  def initialize(model, request)
    @model = model
    @request = request
  end 

  # Says if we are already where we need to be
  # /:id/*slug
  def at_proper_path?
    @request.fullpath == proper_path
  end

  # Returns what the proper path is
  def proper_path
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send(path_name, @model) 
  end

private
  def path_name
    return "edit_#{model_lowercase_name}_path" if @request.filtered_parameters["action"] == "edit"
    "#{model_lowercase_name}_path"
  end

  def model_lowercase_name
    @model.class.name.underscore
  end
end
```

This is easy enough to implement into my controller:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find params[:post_id] || params[:id]
  check_path
end

private
  def check_path
    path_check = PathCheck.new @post, request
    redirect_to path_check.proper_path if !path_check.at_proper_path?
  end
```

My `||` in my `find` method is because in order to maintain resourceful routes, I did something like...

```
resources :posts do
  get '*id' => 'posts#show'
end
```

Which will make a routes like: `/posts/:post_id/*id` on top of `/posts/:id`

This way, the numeric id is primarily used to look up the record, if available. This allows us to loosely match `/posts/12345/not-the-right-slug` to be redirected to `/posts/12345/the-right-slug`

The service is written in a universal fashion, so I can use it in any resourceful controller. I have't found a way to break it yet, but I'm open to correction.

## Resources

> [Railscast #398: Service Objects](http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects) by Ryan Bates
>
> [This Helpful Tweet](https://twitter.com/jfine/status/336571989785452545) by Jared Fine